# What is the relationship between magnetic flux, voltage, induced current and time in a simple AC generator?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, voltage

I've tried deriving the equations for voltage and magnetic flux over the angle between the rotating coil and the magnetic field vectors in this picture.

[image]

But for the induced AC current generated by this rotating coil, how do I derive it's equation over time?

If I use P = VI, I get asymptotes from the resulting equation: I = -k*sec(theta).

If I use V = IR, I get the equation: -k*cos(theta) which contradicts this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A-level_Physics_(Advancing_Physics)/Induction/Worked_Solutions

I really could use some explanation as to how and why the AC current generated behaves the way it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to point 4 in the wiki article, read it again and you'll see that it's not giving the *induced* current, i.e. that resulting from the emf. To find the induced current you use $I=\frac{V}{R}$ as you suggested.

[A small point: it's bad to write things like $\Phi= \text{sin}\ \theta$. For one thing the units don't match. You mean $\Phi= \Phi_{max}\ \text{sin}\ \theta$.]